# C#: How to check all Radio Button's on forms

Tags: c#

I want to check all radio buttons on a form and print the selected button's text on a label. I'm quite newbie to C# and my approach below is not working.

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value;
        bool isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
        if (isChecked)
        {
            value = radioButton1.Text;
        }
        else if (isChecked)
        {
            value = radioButton2.Text;
        }
        else if (isChecked)
        {
            value = radioButton3.Text;
        }
        else if (isChecked)
        {
            value = radioButton4.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            value = radioButton5.Text;
        }
        label2.Text = "Installation location:'" + value;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  For example, why are you repeatedly evaluating isChecked?  It's either true or false and that doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all `RadioButtons` and iterate over the list to get the `Checked` one:

```
foreach (RadioButton rBtn in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    if(rBtn.Checked)
    {
        label2.Text = "Installation location:'" + rBtn.Text;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @CanÖzkan Glad it helped. Mark an answer as answer if it helps you. It will also help other developers to not to read your question again to answer it.